# How to fill Google Sheet via JS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-sheets, frontend

I am just curious to know whether can I fill(write/read) Google Sheets via JavaScript.
Example if someone gives the Google Sheet link can I fill it via API call.

If it's possible do I need a backend server like Node.js or can it be done from frontend only like React.

I know we can use Google Sheet API but I wanted to know whether I can fill the sheets via dynamic sheet id.

**Let's say I have an app where I ask a user to enter their sheet id and a form whose data can be filled in that sheet.**

**I am not talking about a single sheet where I keep the Sheet Id in the env and use it as a CRM or Create one Google Cloud project for Client Secret or API key but I want to grab the Sheet Id dynamically and populate it's content via API.**

I hope I am able to make you understand! All I wanted to know whether can I fill any Sheet if I know it's Id or URL!

Will be happy to know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, it is possible to manipulate a sheet from Google API.

For example, this documentation https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/sheet will show you what you can do with Google API to manipulate sheets.

You could build a NodeJS script using NPM library **[google-spreadsheet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet)**

You will also need to manage the authorization subject and make the user who entered his spreadsheet ID to accept your app getting documents from his workspace.